# JavaScript - passing selected value of a radio button to a javascript function

Tags: javascript

How can I pass the value of a selected radio button to a javascript function in a text input. For instance, I have two radio buttons, and want to pass the selected value to the function e.g. showOptions(this,'RADIO_VALUE',event) where RADIO_VALUE should be replaced with CDD or PF.

```
My radio buttons:
<div class="mb-5">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="type-cdd" value="CDD" >
        <label class="form-check-label" for="type-cdd">CDD</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="type-pf" value="PF" >
        <label class="form-check-label" for="type-pf">PF</label>
    </div>
</div>

My input text box:
<div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 form-group">
        <label for="cdd-domain-accession" class="mb-0">DESCRIPTION HERE</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="domain" placeholder="" name="kw" onkeyup="showOptions(this,'RADIO_VALUE',event)">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add relevant JS of what you have tried

Comment: I strongly encourage you to add the javascript function you want to call (or at least the pseudo-code).  This involves an on-select event, but that's going to be hard to help you without knowing what your JS structure is.

Answer (score 0):

How the event is detected is a bit missing ... In short you can try this

```
var type = document.querySelector('input[name="type"]:checked').value

console.log(type);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see where you have the `showOptions` function, here is my solution >:D

```js
var radios=[...document.all].filter(a=>a.type=="radio") //there probably is some queryselect method that can do the same thing(GET ALL RADIO BUTTONS IN A DOCUMENT)
function radioValue(){ //will return the first radio that is checked(in your case only one radio can be checked at a time so it works) OR return null if no radio is clicked
  try{return radios.filter(a=>a.checked)[0].value}
  catch(err){return null}
}

//now for your showOptions function
function showOptions(elem,value,ev){
  console.log(`The TEXT input element is:\n\n`,elem,`\n\nThe value clicked radio(null if none clicked) is: ${value}\nThe key pressed in the TEXT input element is: ${ev.key}`)
}
```

```html
My radio buttons:
<div class="mb-5">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="type-cdd" value="CDD" >
        <label class="form-check-label" for="type-cdd">CDD</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="type-pf" value="PF" >
        <label class="form-check-label" for="type-pf">PF</label>
    </div>
</div>

My input text box:
<div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 form-group">
        <label for="cdd-domain-accession" class="mb-0">DESCRIPTION HERE</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="domain" placeholder="" name="kw" onkeyup="showOptions(this,radioValue(),event)">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Bomb Squad. I was able to run my showOptions() as expected.

Comment: mind upvoting/marking one of us(u can upvote us both, but u can only `mark` one, u decide ig)